# mvc4 querystring in actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How to make ActionLink that path would look /Book?bookType=textbook.
I tried view bellow but it gives Error "The name 'textbook' does not exist in the current context". I think i'm missing something important. Thanks

```
public class BookController : Controller
{ 
        public ActionResult Index(string bookType, string sortOrder, string searchParams)
        {..}
}
```

view

```
@Html.ActionLink("Učebnice", "Index", "Book", new { bookType = textbook })
```

Comment: Is textbook in your link a variable or should it have quotes around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact,you add an attribute to link tag with name bookType and **textbook**

```
<a href="/Učebnice?Length=4" booktype="textbook">Home</a>
```

so if you want to pass QueryString

1- you have Write textBook in Qoute Mark -> "textbook"
2- use this code ;

```
@Html.ActionLink("Učebnice", "Index", "Book", new { bookType = "textbook" }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Učebnice", "Index", "Book", new { bookType = "textbook" }, null)
```

You need to add the null to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Sure that `textbook` is exist in view and add `null` end of link. Or you can use

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Book", new { bookType = textbook })" >Učebnice</a>
```